# Like Button fan page upload issues

Tags: upload, facebook-like

How do you load the Facebook "Like Button" at the "top" of your home business fan page (to the right of your Facebook company/page name)?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This a **programmers QA site** and as such questions here should be generally related to programming. Please read the [FAQ](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/faq) to learn more about what types of questions are allowed here.

Comment: If the like button is not there - it is probably because what you are looking at is not a Facebook page but a user or a group.  Or you have liked the page already.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot.  You're not allowed to mess with anything outside of the iframe which Facebook gives to your app to play in.